# Map population for related objects

Tags: apex

Looking for an efficient way to accomplish this. I'm a newbie so please bear with.

```
Map<Usage__c, List<Composer__c>> tempMap = new Map<Usage__c, List<Composer__c>>();
Integer composersSize;
Map<Id, Track__c> tracks = new Map<Id, Track__c>([SELECT Id, Artist__c, (Select Id FROM Composers__r), (Select Id FROM Usages__r) FROM Track__c WHERE Id ='a0g1h000000oZjvAAE' ]);
        for(Track__c rec: tracks.values()){
            composersSize = rec.composers__r.size();
            for(Usage__c su : rec.Usages__r){
                tempMap.put(su, rec.Composers__r);
            }
        }
system.debug(composersSize);
system.debug(tempMap.values().size());
```

Composer__c has a lookup to Track__c (Song can have many Composers) and 
Usage__c has a lookup to Track__c (Song can have many Usages)

I wish to map Usage to Composers.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. With the details you have provided in your post, its not very clear what do you want to achieve. Please take a moment and [**edit**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/226560/edit) your post and provide additional details, so that people out here can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing at your intentions here based on your code but something like this (untested and on the fly):

```
Map<Id, Composer__c[]> usageToComposer = new Map<Id,Composer__c[]>();
//Query via Usage the track and composer information where the Track lookup is populated with the Id you desire
for( Usage__c usage : [

    SELECT Id, 
           Track__r.Composer__c 
    From Usage__c 
    Where Track__c = 'a0g1h000000oZjvAAE'

]){
    if(usage.Track__r.Composer__c != null){ //Make sure we have a composer so we are not adding empty records
        Composer__c[] tmp = usageToComposer.get(usage.id); //Grab the list
        if(tmp == null) tmp = new Composer__c[]{}; //See if it has been started, if not instantiate it
        tmp.add(new Composer__c(Id=usage.Track__r.Composer__c)); //Add the composer record
        usageToComposer.put(usage.id,tmp); //Put it al back into the map
    }
}
```

Since you did not provide any additional details or fields this should get you what you need based on your question.

I suspect your needs are going to be much different from this though. However, without additional detail there is not much more color I can provide. You may be getting into the rem of Aggregate queries with Group By Rollup and Cube ....maybe....

You may also want to read up on junction objects to relate the composer to the usages...That brings it own set of challenges but depending on the need it may be the optimal route....